# Заполнение textarea из другого текстового поля

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текстовое поле `<textarea name="has_id" rows="5" class="form-control" id="has_id"></textarea>`
С помощью javascript открываю новое окно где тоже есть текстовое поле которое заполняется из ссылок. 
`<textarea name="hasid_value" rows="5" class="form-control" id="hasid_value"></textarea>` (это поле находится в новом окне которая открыта с помощью JS)
Собственно, вопрос: можно ли как то передать значение текстового поля hasid_value
в текстовое поле has_id которая находится в родительском окне ?
 И, если да, то как ?
 Буду рад за любые ответы.

это код с чем открываается новое окно

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function go(addr) {
  window.open(addr,"MyWin", "menubar=yes,width=750,height=500");
 }
</script>
```

А это ссылка через которую она открывается

```
<a href = '' onclick="go('upload_xray/index.php?id=<?php echo $id ; ?>&sessid=<?php echo $sessid ; ?> '); return false;" class="list-group-item"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Загрузить рентген</a>
```

Comment: дай рабочий код

Comment: Razmik Galstyan, код приведен выше ) какой ещё код дать ? код страницы или как я открываю окно ?

Comment: это не код просто отдельный тег `html` тот код который вы не доделали

Comment: В новом окне - это на другой странице, или в модальном окне?

Comment: @AlexStassov как вы открываете окно. То есть добавьте в вопрос [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[Доступ к новому окну](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83)

```
function go(addr) {
    const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="has_id"]');
    const newWin = window.open(addr, "MyWin", "menubar=yes,width=750,height=500");
    newWin.onload = () => {
      const textarea2 = newWin.document.getElementById('hasid_value');
      textarea2.addEventListener('input', e => textarea.value = textarea2.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил код с которым открываю окно новое

Comment: @AlexStassov обновил ответ

Comment: @AlexStassov Это ваша функция `go`

Comment: Не работает однако. Может я что то не правильно делаю. Короче вместо своей функции go поставил Ваш код. Окно открывает всё нормально. А вот значение не передаеётся ? или может поставить какую то кнопку ?

Comment: Т е не передается значение из нового окна в основное